# Backbone update collection with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, collections

I have a backbone collection with models.

I use file upload plugin:

```
$('#file-areas-fileupload').fileupload({
          ....
          dataType: 'json',
          done: function (e, data) {
               self.collection.parse(data.result);
          }
      });
```

And i want to update existing models in collection when response has come. But:

```
self.collection.parse(data.result);
self.collection.add(data.result);
```

Is not working. Is there a solution to update collection or only way is to `fetch` collection... ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of "e" and "data" by debug in browser or console.log() or alert. In my opinion your code might looked like below

```
self.collection.parse(e.result);
self.collection.add(e.result);
```

Comment: console.log(data.result) returns:

[Object { area_id=1,  campaign_id=607,  id=1428,  more...}, Object { area_id=40,  campaign_id=607,  id=1447,  more...}]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.collection.set(response.result)
```

helped